# Show on chart the now price with label in Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I need to show on chart the now price, for example the price of USDCAD is 1.3554 and I need to show it on a corner with label. How can I do it?

Comment: see https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-print-a-value-at-the-top-right-of-the-chart

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're asking to print the price on the chart so that its always visible, and so it won't scroll with the chart.
currently that's not possible.
anything you plot on the chart with pinescript will scroll with the chart.

what you can do, is plot the value of `close` if `barstate.is_last == true`
you can plot it in a way so you can see it in the scale on the right (but this is redundant to how TradingView already shows the current price). and you can also see if in the Data Window